# Open Text plain when spinner option get selected

Tags: android, spinner, android-spinner

i got a spinner with some options, and i want to change visibility of text box when the specific "other" option get selected , how should i do this ?

```
this.arraySpinner = new String[] {"Mobile", "Gaming", "Media Features", "Medical", "Sports And Nutrition","Security","Space","Other"};
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, arraySpinner);
    categories.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this:**

```
.................
........................

this.arraySpinner = new String[] {"Mobile", "Gaming", "Media Features", "Medical", "Sports And Nutrition","Security","Space","Other"};

// Views
categories= (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

// Adapter
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, arraySpinner);
categories.setAdapter(adapter);

// Set onItemSelected listener to spinner
categories.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            TextView spinnerText = (TextView) view;

            // Checking weather selected item is "Other" or not
            if (spinnerText.getText().equals("Other"))
            {
                // Hide TextView
                textView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); // or View.GONE
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

        }
    });

.............
...................
```

Hope this will help

Comment: My pleasure... Please mark this answer as accepted answer and give an upvote if possible. Read http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

you can Implement OnItemSelected in the spinner and do the things what you want.

```
    categories.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {

        if(arraySpinner!=null && arraySpinner[position].equalIgnoreCase("Other")){
           // your code here
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {
        // your code here
    }

});
```